# object detection LEDs in simple scene

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am new to opencv, I am guessing that this problem could be somewhat simple: I am trying to detect an object which is almost 25 by 15 pixels in an image which is 470 by 590 pixels. [image]

I am attaching a zoomed image of this object, I have several options to go with:

1 - Two close Circles Detection using hough transformation, 
2 - Histogram matching
3 - SURF feature detection

Any advise on which direction should I take? Please consider speed and real-time application. Thanks

Comment: Will your background be black, or can it be anything? Also, are the LEDs guaranteed to be a certain size and orientation? In general: hough transforms are too slow to do in real time; options 2 and 3 will be better on a general background. If the background is dark, simple algorithms based on color or brightness would be fastest.

Comment: @Luke Thank you. Yes, my background is black. I am trying to avoid simple algorithms cause there might be another bright objects which might not be the two LEDs which I am looking for...

Comment: OpenCV has a blob detector that is (also) used for the (a)symetrical circle pattern calibration. It should be able to detect the centers of circular blobs such as these leds.

Comment: I think this could help in you case http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/bounding_rotated_ellipses/bounding_rotated_ellipses.html?highlight=contours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should go without explicitly saying so, but there are probably hundreds of things that could be tried, and with only one example image it is quite difficult to advise.  For instance are the LED always green?  we don't know.

That aside, imho, two good places to start would be with the ol' faithful template matching, or blob detection.

Then if that is not robust enough, you will need to look at some alternative representations of the template/blob, like the classic HoG (good for shape, maybe a bit heavy this app.), or even your own bespoke one that encodes your own domain specific knowledge of this problem.

Then if that is not robust enough, build a dataset of representative +ve and -ve examples, as big as you can, and then train a machine like svm , or a boosted classifier.

Template Matching:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html

Blob detection:

https://code.google.com/p/cvblob/

Machine Learning:

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/ml.html

TIPS: 
Add as much domain knowledge as possible, i.e. if they are always green, use color in the representation, like hog on g channel for instance.  If they are always circular, try to encode that, like use a log-polar grid in the template,rather than a regular grid... and so on.

Machine Learning is not magic, a linear classifier will essentially weight different points in the feature space, so you still require a good representation, so if the Template matching was a total fail, the it is unlikely that simple linear ml with help, but if the Template matching was okay, then ml may well boost the performance to a good level.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The LEDs are always green. Do you think Template matching for 25 by 25 kernel will be fast enough?

Comment: @Samer I think it would depend on the implementation and representation and distance function, and of-coarse most importantly the size of the image :) i.e. would working on a smaller scale, really hurt the performance?  As far as the opencv one goes, i suppose you could just try and see...

Comment: @Samer oh, and also a simple trick for speed up is called a cascade. In your case, as a first level in your cascade you could eliminate most of the image pixels by employing a simple threshold, removing most of the obvious black area, then pass the resulting mask to the template matcher for the final stage. This will reduce the computational burden on the template matcher.

Answer (score 0):

step 1:  Remove the black background.

step 2:  A snake algorithm can be used to find the boundaries of your object

Comment: or you can use snake directly without step1